# Download.file URL of zip file changed from 'http:' to 'https"

Tags: r, rcurl, download.file

I am a little rusty as I don't use R as much as before.

I have R code that I wrote years ago that suddenly stopped working when the source URL changed from a 'http:" to "http**s**:"

```
destfile = "C:/Temp/tmpcftc.zip"
url = "http://www.cftc.gov/files/dea/history/com_disagg_txt_2015.zip"
download.file(url, destfile)
df = read.csv(unz(destfile, "c_year.txt"))
```

When the code stopped working I noticed that the URL changed to "https:" so I made the following change:

```
destfile = "C:/Temp/tmpcftc.zip"
url = "https://www.cftc.gov/files/dea/history/com_disagg_txt_2015.zip"
download.file(url, destfile)
df = read.csv(unz(destfile, "c_year.txt"))
```

But, now I get the following error:

```
trying URL 'https://www.cftc.gov/files/dea/history/com_disagg_txt_2015.zip'
Error in download.file(url, destfile) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://www.cftc.gov/files/dea/history/com_disagg_txt_2015.zip'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile) :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'An error occurred in the secure channel support'
```

I can download the URL without issue from the internet browser but not with the code above.

Any assistance in pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Works for me without any issue. But there is a fragment in `?download.file()` help, stating about libcurl certificates. What about switching the `method` to wget, like `download.file(url, tempfile(), method = "wget")`?

Comment: Thanks, although frustrating that it works for you without issue as it still errors for me. Your suggestion to add method="wget" also did not work as it returned  'wget' call had nonzero exit status error

Answer (score 2):

I could reproduce the error. Solution for me was to add the line

```
CURL_SSL_BACKEND=openssl
```

to the .Renviron file. Restart R and the download should work with the code from the question.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and while it did not do the trick it lead me to an eventual solution. Turns out, I had a really old version of OpenSSL. I upgraded my R install to the latest version and reinstalled my packages and presto I had a newer version of SSL and the code from the question worked perfectly.